# Frechet distance in O(n)

Tags: algorithm, math, time-complexity, distance

I have seen on a number of articles that the [Fréchet algorithm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fr%C3%A9chet_distance) complexity is `O(n^2)`.
That the paths represent as an `Q` and `P` arrays, of `n` size each

What if I start from `Q[0]`, `P[0]` and check all the possibilities and choose the minimal:

```
STP_i,j = min(|Q[i] - P[j+1]|, |Q[i+1] - P[j+1]|,|Q[i+1] - P[j]|)
```

And change the `i` and `j` accordingly.
So I can get the answer on O(n).

Am I wrong?

Comment: If you are iterating over all the possible pairs `i, j`, that is O(n²) (pick a value of `n` and you will see you get `n * n` pairs)

Comment: Can you create an example that my algorithm do not work?

Comment: It's not that the algorithm does not work (I can't tell for sure since I'm not familiar with the problem but it seems reasonable). What I mean is that an algorithm that iterates over every possible pair of values `i, j`, where `i` and `j` can take values from 1 to n, has a complexity of O(n²) (assuming each iteration is O(1), like in this case). If you check the number of iterations for each value of n you will see it increases quadratically, not linearly.

Comment: Q and P arrays increase, and we want to find path with minimum  |Q[i] - P[j]| in the total so i<i+1 and j<j+1 gives me "hint" about the 2D array

Comment: Ah okay I think I see what you mean now, I wasn't understanding it correctly. I think there are counterexamples for that, I'll post now.

Answer (score 1):

Consider the next example:

[image: Lines]

Take the dots marked with black as the beginning of the lines. In the first step, your algorithm would advance one point in both lines. However, the Fréchet distance in this case would be the distance between the first red point and the third blue point, but since your algorithm has already move away from the first point it will give you a larger value.

Comment: Whet if the every point is after(on the x-axis) the previous point?

Comment: @alexarcasm I _think_ if you require that both axes grow monotonically in both lines then it's valid (you can think of an example like above but 90º rotated, and slightly changed to have increasing X). There is probably some broader geometrical/topological condition for which it is valid, you could consider asking about it in Mathematics.SE.